# Automatic creation and setup of PPTP VPN

Tags: automation, rras, pptp

I have several (~75) users that need to setup a VPN connection to a RRAS server using PPTP. Now, I can manually create these connections no problem, but it's time consuming. I'd much rather email them a batch script, or something similar, and have them run it.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [Connection Manager Administation Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739464(WS.10).aspx). You can use this tool to create a program to automatically configure client computers with a "connection" to your VPN server. It's actaully rather nice to use. We take the output from the CMAK and deploy it onto clients with startup scripts, but you could definitely email the resulting program (or a link thereto) to clients for them to execute.

Comment: I can't seem to find a download link, where do I go to find that?

Comment: The CMAK is an Add/Remove Windows Components option in Windows Server 2003 and an a "feature" (if I recall properly) on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

If these are active directory clients and you are running server 2008/sbs 2008, there are now group policy 'preferences' that allow you to push out configurations for PPTP VPN's/Printers/Drive Maps/Files/Folders/Registry entries really nicely.

You need to install a client side 'policy extensions' update for XP/Vista clients (already in windows 7) which can be found as an optional update on windows update, but once installed the number of extra GPO pushable items makes it really worth it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943729